# PATCH e PUT rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou fazendo um teste para um estagio onde eu tenho uma api e nessa api tenho que ter o method PUT para alterar dados de um usuário pelo id e um método PATCH que altera os dados parciais de um usuário mas que caso ele não exista irá criá-lo.

```
def update
    @user = ApiModel.find(params[:id])


    @user.update(user_params)
end
```

Qual o melhor jeito de fazer o PATCH para que caso não exista o usuário crie ele?

Answer (score 0):

A chamada `ApiModel.find(params[:id])` vai disparar uma exceção se o registro não existir no banco (estou assumindo que você está usando `ActiveRecord`).

Você pode usar o `ApiModel.find_by(id: params[:id])` para fazer a consulta sem que uma exceção seja disparada. Assim, como resultado você terá o usuário encontrado ou nulo (`nil`) como retorno.

Aí é só controlar o fluxo com `@user.present?` e fazer as ações necessárias.

---

*Eu ia sugerir que você fizesse a chamada `ApiModel.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_create`, mas preciso te alertar que é estranho alguém chamar a sua API para atualizar parcialmente um usuário com um ID que não existe. Digo isso porque se o usuário não existir, ele será criado com um ID diferente do que foi passado na API (por depender de um valor sequencial do banco de dados).*